# Campaign measurement is not sent to Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

I am following campaign measurement guide to do

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

1. Google Play Campaign Attribution
2. General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution

For the Google Play Campaign Attribution, after adding the campaign service and receiver to the androidManifest.xml, i followed the testing guide.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

In the log successfully received the install referrer intent.

07-29 17:05:32.968 8333-8363/? D/GAv4: Received installation campaign: content=test_content, keyword=test_term, medium=test_medium, name=test_name, source=test_source

But in my google analytic account, Acquisition -> Sources -> All, nothing shows up. Can anyone have any idea what is the root cause?

I also implemented the hit screen analytic, this is working.

My google-services.json is below:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "123456788680",
    "project_id": "test-app-project"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:12345678680:android:488edac1c6c2df62",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.test.analytic"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxKoT0XEkMgOCUe0c"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "UA-xxxxxxxx-2"
          }
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:12345678680:android:6092a3d09b6b18d2",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.test"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxKoT0XEkMgOCUe0c"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "UA-xxxxxxxx-2"
          }
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I modified the project name and the key to post here. In my actual project, i didn't modify anything. There are 2 clients with different package name, because i have 2 projects, one is the main entry app and another is the library. All both needs to send info the google analytic. But both in one application, so I set it to use the same analytic property when request configuration form google. Is that impact? I think it shouldn't.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the information was not sent before building the tracker for the first time. 
After sending the broadcast I also only get:

```
D/GAv4: Received installation campaign: content=test_content, keyword=test_term, medium=test_medium, name=test_name, source=test_source
```

Then after sending my first own tracking information to Google Analytis, I get:

```
D/GAv4: Sending first hit to property: UA-63098830-1
D/GAv4: Found relevant installation campaign: content=test_content, keyword=test_term, medium=test_medium, name=test_name, source=test_source
D/GAv4: Sending installation campaign to: UA-63098830-1, content=test_content, keyword=test_term, medium=test_medium, name=test_name, source=test_source
```